# "where" restrictions not working on hql query with join clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql

First of all clarify that I am quite bad with databases, so please do not be to mean with my code :P

I have a problem with a query on hibernate using join and restrictions. I have a huge list of `Assignments` and some of them have an `Asr` object.

```
queryString.append("select new commons.bo.assignment.AssignmentAssociateExtract("
    + " assignment.id, assignment.contract.assignmentStatus,"
    + " assignment.contract.beginDate, assignment.contract.endDate,"
    + " assignment.contract.contractType, assignment.organizationalData.homeCountryKey,"
    + " assignment.organizationalData.hostCountryKey," 
    + " assignment.organizationalData.homeOrgUnitKey,"
    + " assignment.associate.globalIdAssociate,"
    + " assignment.associate.localIdHome,"
    + " assignment.associate.firstName,"
    + " assignment.associate.lastName)"
    + " from Assignment assignment left join assignment.asr asr"
    + " where assignment.contract.assignmentStatus.code = 5"
    + " and asr.homeAsrElegibility is not 'X'"
    + " or asr.homeAsrElegibility is null"
);
```

I was creating this query step by step. Before I created it without the join clause `left join assignment.asr asr` and it was working well but of course it was not showing the `Assignments` that did not have a `Asr` object. After I added the join clause, now it shows every single `Assignment` (10.000 records when those who have an `assignmentStatus = 5` are just 4.000) and the restrictions like

```
where assignment.contract.assignmentStatus.code = 5
```

are not reflected in the result anymore.

So to sum up: I need a list with all assignments with assignmentStatus = 5 and asr.homeAsrElegibility != 'X'. But it needs to include also all assignments with assignmentStatus = 5 even if they do not have an Asr object.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis helps to clarify the situation.

```
queryString.append("select new commons.bo.assignment.AssignmentAssociateExtract("
    + " assignment.id, assignment.contract.assignmentStatus,"
    + " assignment.contract.beginDate, assignment.contract.endDate,"
    + " assignment.contract.contractType, assignment.organizationalData.homeCountryKey,"
    + " assignment.organizationalData.hostCountryKey," 
    + " assignment.organizationalData.homeOrgUnitKey,"
    + " assignment.associate.globalIdAssociate,"
    + " assignment.associate.localIdHome,"
    + " assignment.associate.firstName,"
    + " assignment.associate.lastName)"
    + " from Assignment assignment left join assignment.asr asr"
    + " where assignment.contract.assignmentStatus.code = 5"
    + " and ((asr.homeAsrElegibility is not null and asr.homeAsrElegibility is not 'X')"
    + " or (asr.homeAsrElegibility is null))"
);
```

Comment: you are right! I was trying deleting the `is not 'X'` clause and just leaving the last one and of course deleting the `or` keyword and it works. Thanks!